# Commit all modified files to Github in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, github

In our project we are using Netbeans. When I try to commit the files I have modified in Netbeans it only brings up the current file and I have to do a commit for every file I have modified. I have seen where my co-worker can hit "Commit" and it will bring up every file he has modified, but neither of us know how to change the settings to allow multiple file commits.

I've tried looking online for options, but haven't found an answer. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the answer. Hopefully it will help another lost soul in the future.

Right click on the project name -> Git -> Commit.

Comment: In Netbeans if you have a file as your active window then it will only commit that file. 

To commit multiple modified files right click on the name of the project in the Project Window (usually on the left of the screen--you can also go to "Window" in the menu and activate it there), select Git, and then select commit.

Comment: in the question title you mention github, and yet in the question body you don't mention github at all and it seems like you're simply referring to git. and then in your answer you don't do anything with github, and yet it's the accepted answer. if you were just trying to do a simple git commit you should change the title of the question to "Commit all modified file to Git in Netbeans." you're answer helped me, but i almost didn't look at it because i wasn't trying to "Commit all modified files to Github in Netbeans" i was trying to "Commit all modified files to Git in Netbeans"

Answer (score 1):

You can press on **Team** and then **Commit**. Then follow instructions etc... I did this method for a few weeks, then after attempt to get this project on other computer, I realised that my project other files were old untouched.

But if you follow this:

> Okay, I figured out the answer. Hopefully it will help another lost soul in the future.
>
> Right click on the project name -> Git -> Commit.

It works with all files!

Comment: The question says _"When I try to commit the files I have modified in Netbeans it only brings up the current file"_, so other than state the issue in the question and copy the accepted answer what does this answer actually contribute?